# Outlook: Rule for a specific email address in CC

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

I am using Outlook 2010 in my office. I have one business inbox and several shared inboxes.

For my own inbox I use many rules. One of them applies gray text color on mails which are sent to me in CC.

Now I want to use such a rule on the shared inboxes as well, where mails are marked that are sent to this specific inbox only in CC.
Outlook just offers conditions for "my name in CC", but not something like "a specific name in CC" where I could use the mail address of the shared inbox.

How can such a rule be set up? - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods described here should work. [Configuring message rules for a shared mailbox](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/794)

With Outlook 2010 this works for me:

**Separate mail profile**

If you want to manage the rules for the shared mailbox in Outlook but are still using Outlook 2007 or previous, then you have to use the Mail applet in Control Panel to create an additional mail profile.

You'd then set up this mail profile with the shared mailbox as the main mail account rather then your own. This also requires you that you either have been granted Full Access permissions to this shared mailbox or have been provided credentials for it.

Answer (score 0):

check this link: https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-move-email-specific-cc-recipients/

You have to unlock developer tab and insert the VBA code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1118466)